# How can I merge two queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a query on a table:

```
@answears = Answear.where("round_id = ? AND group_id <> ? AND value <> 'HIGHNOON'", @round.id, @group.id
```

which works, returning what I want. But elsewhere, there is another query:

```
@answears = Answear.where(:group_id => [1, 3, 5])
```

whichs works too.

How can I merge these two in one?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but is Answear supposed to be Answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply chain them.

```
Answear.where("round_id = ? AND group_id <> ? AND value <> 'HIGHNOON'", @round.id, @group.id).where(:group_id => [1, 3, 5])
```

Two notes you might want to consider:

1. You have group_id in your query twice this way. It would make more sense to just make sure `@group.id` isn't in the array of group ids you are passing to the `where` method.
2. Answear is not a word. You should probably name your model Answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `IN (?)` with an array value:

```
@answears = Answear.where("round_id = ? AND group_id IN (?) AND value <> 'HIGHNOON'", @round.id, [1, 3, 5])
```